# Run docker with volume mapping from another docker container

Tags: docker

I have a Jenkins instance running in a Docker container which can also run docker commands of the host.

The build process of my apps includes running bower and grunt. But to avoid having to install node on the Jenkins container, I wish to run a seperate node-container to perform the node-specific commands.

ie. this works if I run this locally on my machine:
    docker run -it -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app 3bdigital/bower-grunt-gulp bower install
I basically mount my project folder to the app folder and the container will run bower install in that folder.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work if I run this command from inside the Jenkins container. The docker container runs, but the volume is not being mounted properly.

Is there a way to do this ? Or do I have to install Node in my Jenkins image ?

Another solution is to install node in the image of the app itself and have that docker image do the necessary build steps. The downside is that this image will be much larger than necessary (the node_modules, bower_components, source, ... folders are not needed in production)

Comment: Why isn't the volume mounting properly? In what way?
It sounds like you have a more general problem with Docker, that's not specifically related to your situation. Looking past the complexity of your situation may help you find the source of the problem :)

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. The docker container with Grunt and Bower runs but throws an error saying package.json doesn't exist, or bower.json doesn't exist. When I use bash inside the container, I see that my project files are not where they supposed to be...

Comment: Have you tried using docker inspect container_name and looked for what volumes are mounted? Maybe it's mounting the wrong thing, or to the wrong place.

Comment: The docker inspect returns this info:

            "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/sixonfire.testlocatie.be/workspace",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],

Comment: The folder shown is the pwd from inside Jenkins. I suspect that docker doesn't know that and is looking for the given folder on the host machine...

Comment: It sounds like you're right. How are you running Docker commands on the host from within a container? I'd have said that wasn't possible.  
Certainly, what -v does is mount a directory from the host, so one would expect it to do what it's done here.  
It is possible to run Docker in Docker ("dind"), where by I'd imagine you could launch a container (x) from a container (y), and container y would be the "host".  
In this case, could you not simply mount Jenkins and the other container to the same directory on the host? That way they can both access it, without having to mount to each other.

Comment: I mounted the docker.sock from the host machine to the Jenkins container. This allows Jenkins to execute docker commands.

I found a few alternative solutions but all are a bit funky...
- Run jenkins in "privilaged" mode and have it run its own docker (dind)
- SSH back to the host server and run commands there
- Change the path to the absolute path where Docker keeps the jenkins volume on the host disk